System.FormatException in a mediaType for a httpclient get request
I need to make a request using this specific mediatype application/vnd.wolt.order+json;version=2beta1
Here is my code:
 var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://pos-integration-service.wolt.com/orders/66e41e1459cade439d415f8f");
    request.Headers.Add("WOLT-API-KEY", "xxxx");
    var content = new StringContent(string.Empty);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.wolt.order+json;version=2beta1");
    request.Content = content;
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

The error i get is that application/vnd.wolt.order+json;version=2beta1 is not valid.
I have copy c# code from postman. In postman request works fine
I dont know what is wrong

That constructor expects just a media type, not parameters, so ;version=2beta1 gets rejected.
You need to use MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse to parse the whole thing:
content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.wolt.order+json;version=2beta1");


Thank you i change it but now i am getting error system.net.protocolviolationexception 'cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.'

Well, yeah. You can't include a body in a GET request, that's not valid.

your code works but only in net 7 and above in net framework it doesnt. Thank you at all
